# How to create dependencies in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to improve my project layout.

Here's (some of) my `CMakeLists.txt` files:

```
project(Numerical CXX)

include(cotire)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(hw1 hw1.cpp
    linalg/lu.cpp
    linalg/banded.cpp
)

add_executable(hw2 hw2.cpp
    linalg/cholesky.cpp
    linalg/lu.cpp
    linalg/banded.cpp
)

add_executable(hw3 hw3.cpp
    linalg/solvers-new.cpp
    linalg/cholesky.cpp
    linalg/lu.cpp
    linalg/banded.cpp
)
...
```

`lu.h` includes `banded.h`, so anything that needs `lu` will also need `banded`. This requires redundancy in my project as seen above. Is there a way that I don't have to add `banded.cpp` every time I add `lu.cpp`?

Comment: Why not reduce compile times and make them a library?

Comment: @kfsone: that sounds like the kind of thing I would like to do! How would I go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Amadeus's answer works, but I think a better answer is to take the common files and move them into a library:

```
project(Numerical CXX)
include(cotire)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_library(CommonLib STATIC
    linalg/lu.cpp
    linalg/banded.cpp
)

add_executable(hw1 
    hw1.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(hw1 LINK_PUBLIC 
    CommonLib
)

add_executable(hw2 
    hw2.cpp
    linalg/cholesky.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(hw2 LINK_PUBLIC 
    CommonLib
)

add_executable(hw3 
    hw3.cpp
    linalg/solvers-new.cpp
    linalg/cholesky.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(hw3 LINK_PUBLIC 
    CommonLib
)
```

Comment: How do I decide what goes into the library?

Comment: @krey Whatever you commonly re-use amongst all your modules - there's no reason you can't just put everything you're going to use under linalg into it. The linking process will extract only the required functions into the resultant binary.